# Triggering Cloud Run API from a Memorystore Redis PubSub Message

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redis, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-memorystore

I have a Redis instance running in GCP Memorystore, and I have enabled `notify-keyspace-events` on this instance. My ultimate goal is to publish messages from my Redis instance when certain keys expire, and on these events, make a call to a service I have on Cloud Run with the data of the key as input.

How do I think about building this? Only way I can think is to have a thread always running in my Cloud Run instance to check for new messages in Redis Pub/Sub channels. I am afraid this might not work though as Cloud Run is not going to allow background tasks.

I am thinking of a way to generate a POST request to my Cloud Run service when the Redis message is generated, but could not find a way to do this yet.

Answer (score 0):

What I know so far of that can be integrated together is Cloud Pub/Sub with Cloud Run as stated in these guides [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/pubsub#run_pubsub_server-python) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/pubsub-push#run_pubsub_handler-python).

What I don't know for sure is if you will be able to somehow publish events from your GCP Memorystore to a Pub/Sub topic. Maybe, if you are able to read in real time which Redis keys inspire, you could manually publish these events as messages to your Pub/Sub topìc, and then your Cloud Run subscribe to the same topic to receive the messages from it.

Another thing you could consider is using [Cloud Background Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/background#functions_background_parameters-python).

As for sending a direct POST request to your Cloud Run service, the following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service) could be useful for you.